# Making changes with ifconfig persistent

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, router, gateway, dhcp

can anyone tell me on how to make the following commandline changes persistent? (Like via /etc/network/interfaces or /etc/dhcpcd.conf)

```
route del default
ifconfig eth0 add 172.25.1.1 netmask 255.240.0.0
ifconfig eth0:0 netmask 255.240.0.0
route del default
route add default gw 172.25.0.1
```

I need to make these changes to make this RPI use a Router as a default gateway a room next to ours.
For more info: We don't have direct access to this Router, as in we can't make any changes to it by ourselves.

Am thankful for any insightful responses.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dhcp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the route permanent, you need to create a static route configuration file. Create a file with the name route-interface in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory, such as `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`

Then, add the same line you would with ip route add:

```
172.16.5.0/24 via 10.0.0.101 dev eth0
```

Make sure to restart your network settings so they take effect:

```
# service network restart
```